# Why would you use link tags with a data/css HREF instead of using a style tag?

Tags: html, css, data-uri

In Facebook's source code, you can find the following [source code](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HWVnrSzqr_eF__DPGagWVDXLM1q8JouI9FcgfuY08ia4EgbpxMmZEqU6X6b8TpbI-8u9EjpLdSmTpirA_gZ3us8_8t3R5_OOo11s2Qr8oo7taVQRdn-mVt40MPNeZjRJDMdwO1B2Fis0rBqfOdpqB3z_SE1eT_4Xjl7CYCTwHdmjPicEatGuTYeWoqHBb3rJMh8bah6XHiVny0dSGPayjp9R6pQ-CWc6aYHuiIbRFH6HEIdds_bBBqRG8-TEuXzSC50e5xp0xXe5SnRzThweX2t1PTcq40XNLpm1fqZ13apfbhSs3wwTNlI5uRsTVsv0zYJjMciLhQpGcWNxclOs_08GcCe31IaMM4cC13OuLAuC_itOqZ8d9-Y4P8qhRsgStcRR9W_2QJikEpluCQIGyVnk5VENyjaXExDM6CFVM70YWsciVr2o2Zh5VEzfwPw5oyRuPfMoW6LnbnYvNIVzjSyHNjFdI8AxmAKLRhJDd7gU_qy5SBhOW8Wz_pCHJIxTLRKGXUytvidUFaGfp3fIDZtX562eneS8IsMhLP5vlO3IGD7WjCVu8UQZkgE10aEGZlbdDTlA9IEJAMzLR9Zji9Wxha4h8mYOLxvuZQDKlAGRLJbHkV1jh72QVxr0WXNmWunBjOoBobEa4P6m8f6D9P4eexvR89c2yVA9CQT_Gw=w1232-h103-no) which I'm having to post as a link instead of an image as I'm new to the site.

For reference, it's a HTML `<link>` tag with the `href` property beginning with `data:text/css; charset=utf-8,` with CSS then following on.

Why would you use that tag over a `<style>` tag which is designed for storing and using CSS?

Comment: Pure speculation, but maybe to hide from older browsers? For example, the link won't work on its own in IE.

Comment: @Alohci: I thought so initially as `<style>` was introduced in HTML 3.2 and `<link>` in HTML 2, but caniuse.com says that data URIs were introduced to IE8 released 2009.

Comment: Yes, but only Base64 encoded ones, not the form used in your Facebook sample.

Comment: Ah, my bad. That might make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element

The difference between the two is that you can re-use a link to a .css in many different pages where a style block would have to be written on every single page.
A site that has many different pages would rather link to a .css and keep all the pages looking the same than have to re-write the Style block over and over.
    `<link href="#" rel="stylesheet" />`    --> goes and gets an already written .css file.
    
    div{
    border:1px solid black;
    }

--> is written on the page and it's scope is only to that single page.

Comment: They're not linking to a CSS file though. They're linking to a `data` URI.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: I just don't understand why they use it like that rather than in a `<style>` block.